numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject error
I am trying to import pmdarima, but it gives the error ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, which may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from the C header, got 88 from PyObject
I uninstalled Numpy version 2.0+ and installed Numpy version 1.26.4, but it still gives me the same error.

Can you formulate a clear question?

This question is similar to: ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did you figure it out?
